# Login from txt file with attempt limits

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

i'm totally new to C++ and this forum. I tried searching the codes and found a piece of code but it doesn't work as what I wanted. I want a login that check every line of the txt file and grant access to the system if the username and password is correct.

```
string line = " ";
ifstream readfile("Login.txt");
string username, password, adminname, adminpass;
cout << "\nEnter Username: ";
cin >> username;
cout << "\nEnter Password: ";
cin >> password;
while (getline(readfile, line)) 
{
    stringstream iss(line);
    iss >> adminname >> adminpass;
    //Login Success Function
    if (username == adminname && password == adminpass) 
    {
        cout << "\nLOGIN SUCCESSFUL!";

    }
}
//Login Fail Function
{
    int fail = 5;
    while (fail > 0)
    {
        cout << "Error! Invalid Username and Password. Please reenter.\n";
        cout << "You have " << fail << " tries left.\n";
        cout << "\nEnter Username: ";
        cin >> username;
        cout << "\nEnter Password: ";
        cin >> password;
        fail--;
    }
    cout << "\nACCESS DENIED!";
}
```

The txt file consists of 1st line (admin123 password123), 2nd line (admin admin).
The login worked fine if I entered correctly however, if I enter wrong username or password I just stuck in the while loop until it shows access denied even if I enter correct username and password for the second try.

Can anyone help me to fix this? If possible please include the comments(the //) so that I am able to learn from it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the text file first, storing in a `std::map<std::string, std::string>`, then do all of the prompting and each time, check to see if `mymap[username] == password`.

Comment: @crashmstr Please no(!) mymap[username] here!

Comment: @DieterLücking what would be wrong with that? (Other than having a plain text file of usernames and passwords to begin with, which can't be secure).

Comment: *Do not store passwords in plaintext.* Ever.

Comment: @crashmstr mymap[username] will create a new entry if the user name does not exist

Comment: @crashmstr can you provide the code and show me how it works please?
This is just a simply class assignment so for now i'm using it as plaintext

Comment: @DieterLücking So? Unless you have a blank `password`, it won't match. In this case, it does no harm. Also not like we are talking about 50k records or anything, and for the small data he is going to have, it is simple and works.

Comment: @crashmstr login("intruder", "");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention in the comments that this is an assignment, I'm going to keep this pretty general.

In your program, you prompt once for username and password, then read through the file to see if there is a match.

If there is no match, you then prompt for username and password again in a loop, but do not check to see if they are valid. This is what the problem is. Each time you get a new username and password, check to see if they are valid.

There are (at least) two possible approaches:

1. Include the "fail" and re-prompt logic around the code that reads the file. So you get a username and password, then read the file checking for a match. If no match, do it again. In this case, you would be reading the file each time. For a large data-set, this could get slow. For this problem, it should be fine.
2. Read the file once and save the values (Have you studied arrays, vectors, or other data structures? You need at least some of those things to do this). I would use a `std::map` here because it is direct access and would be the smallest amount of code, but there are many other ways to do this as well.

Here is a possible way to do it with re-reading the file. Note that this mostly just re-organizing the code you already have:

```
bool success = false; //use this as part of our loop condition
int fail = 5;
while (!success && fail > 0) //loop until we succeed or failed too much
{
    //get the username and password
    cout << "\nEnter Username: ";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "\nEnter Password: ";
    cin >> password;

    //open the file and see if we have a match
    ifstream readfile("Login.txt");
    while (getline(readfile, line)) 
    {
        stringstream iss(line);
        iss >> adminname >> adminpass;
        //Login Success Function
        if (username == adminname && password == adminpass) 
        {
            //we have a match, so set success to true so we exit the loop
            success = true;
        }
    }

    if (!success) //we did not find a match in the file
    {
        //so we output the message
        cout << "Error! Invalid Username and Password. Please reenter.\n";
        cout << "You have " << fail << " tries left.\n";
        fail--;
    }
}

//now we know if we had success or not, so report it
if (success)
{
    cout << "\nLOGIN SUCCESSFUL!";
}
else
{
    cout << "\nACCESS DENIED!";
}
```

Comment: I tried using else after the if statement but no luck. Nope..didn't learn anything like that..